# Netcat - socket in time_wait when echoing and piping, but not when invoked directly

Tags: netstat, netcat, time-wait

I'm testing an application using `netcat (nc)` and I'm getting very low throughput on network connections.  When I ran `netstat -tnpo` I see numerous `TCP` sessions in `TIME_WAIT`.  I'm sending data to my application via a `bash script` as indicated below:

```
while true; do
    echo "<required string>" | nc server_ip port
done
```

If I instead do this at the `terminal`:

```
nc server_ip port
<required string>
```

the connection terminates immediately and there is no TCP session left in TIME_WAIT.

Why the difference?  What do I need to do differently to ensure that after each echo, no TCP port is left in TIME_WAIT?

Comment: Pass it `--send-only`, I think.

Comment: Hmmm - my version of netcat (**netcat-openbsd**  `1.105-7ubuntu1`) doesn't have that option.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use it like this.

```
    while true; do
        echo "<required string>" | nc server_ip port < /dev/null   
    done
```

Apologies I don't have enough repo to post it like a comment.

Comment: What's the point of both piping something to `nc` and redirecting its input from `/dev/null`?

Comment: @tollboy Same result anyway